# R - Select files by dates in filenames

Tags: r, date, long-filenames

I already had a similar question here: 
[R - How to choose files by dates in file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521355/r-how-to-choose-files-by-dates-in-file-names)

But I have to do a little change.

I still have a list of filenames, similar to that:

```
list = c("AT0ACH10000700100dymax.1-1-1993.31-12-2003",
         "AT0ILL10000700500dymax.1-1-1990.31-12-2011", 
         "AT0PIL10000700500dymax.1-1-1992.31-12-2011",
         "AT0SON10000700100dymax.1-1-1990.31-12-2011",
         "AT0STO10000700100dymax.1-1-1992.31-12-2006",  
         "AT0VOR10000700500dymax.1-1-1981.31-12-2011",
         "AT110020000700100dymax.1-1-1993.31-12-2001",
         "AT2HE190000700100dymax.1-1-1973.31-12-1994", 
         "AT2KA110000700500dymax.1-1-1991.31-12-2010", 
         "AT2KA410000700500dymax.1-1-1991.31-12-2011")
```

I already have a command to sort out files that a certain length of recording (for example 10 in this case):

```
#Listing Files (creates the list above)
files = list.files(pattern="*00007.*dymax", recursive = TRUE)

#Making date readable
split_daymax = strsplit(files, split=".", fixed=TRUE)

from = unlist(lapply(split_daymax, "[[", 2))
to = unlist(lapply(split_daymax, "[[", 3))
from = as.POSIXct(from, format="%d-%m-%Y")
to = as.POSIXct(to, format="%d-%m-%Y")

timelistmax = difftime(to, from, "days")

#Files with more than 10 years of recording
index = timelistmax >= 10*360
filesdaymean = filesdaymean[index]
```

My problem is now that I have way too many files and no computer can handle that.

Now I only want to read in files that contain files from 1993 (or any other certain year I want) on and have 10 years of recording from then on, so the recordings should be at least until 2003.

So the file 1973-1994 should not be included, but the file from 1981- 2011 is fine.

I dont know how to select a year in this case.

I am thankful for any help

Comment: `1973-1994` is more than 10 years

Comment: Of course, at least 10 years! It can be also more. But 1973-1994 is not good because I am interested in the time from 1993-2003. And that file only contains 1 year in that periode. Sorry when that was unclear. I want files that contain the years 1993-2003. I want to exclude files like the mentioned one because it only has 1 year in that periode and I want only files that have at least 10 years. So 1993-2010 or so would also be fine.

Comment: I guess you may need to mention that it should be multiples of 10 or 10

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: BTW, in the `list` you gave, is it only 1, 6, and 10 you want to select?  In that case `list[!sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(list, "(?<=-)[0-9]{4}"), function(x) diff(as.numeric(x))) %% 10 ]#[1] "AT0ACH10000700100dymax.1-1-1993.31-12-2003" "AT0VOR10000700500dymax.1-1-1981.31-12-2011"
[3] "AT2KA410000700500dymax.1-1-1991.31-12-2011"`
`

Comment: No! I want to have all apart from 6 and 7! Look: I am interested in the years from 1993-2003. So the 2nd file for example is also good because it contains this time. I can just cut away the years I am not interested in. The 6th file for example is too short. It starts 1993, which is ok, but it already ends in 2001, so 2 years are missing that thats not ok.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting the logic

Comment: Hmm, I dont know what is so difficult in it. :/ I want files that contain the years from 1993-2003, not shorter, but longer is no problem!

Comment: As I said, I didn't get your logic.  Based on the earlier logic you mentioned, I showed a code, then you are saying that all apart from 6 and 7 which I don't get it on what logic it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
fileDates <- str_extract_all(files, "[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}")

find_file <- function(x, whichYear, noYears = 10) {
  start <- as.Date(x[[1]], "%d-%m-%Y")
  end <- as.Date(x[[2]], "%d-%m-%Y")
  years <- as.numeric(end-whichYear, units = "days")/365
  years > noYears & (year(start) <= year(whichYear) & 
                       year(end) >= year(whichYear))
}
sapply(fileDates, find_file, whichYear = as.Date("1993-01-01"), noYears = 10)
```

You have two conditions which you can calculate first the number of years since 1993 and then use boolean logic to figure out if 1993 is within the date range.

Comment: Thank you! That worked and I get the result I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Using `files`, `to`, and `from` as you've defined them above, this should get get you files that contain atleast a ten year span of data between 1993 and 2003:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(file_name = files, file_start = from, file_end = to)
df_index <- year(df$file_start) <=1993 & year(df$file_end) >= 2003
files_to_load <- df$file_name[df_index]
```

If a base only solution is desired, turn the POSIXct to POSIXlt and extract the year component as such:

```
df <- data.frame(file_name = files, 
                 file_start = as.POSIXlt(from), 
                 file_end = as.POSIXlt(to))

df_index <- (df$file_start$year+1900 <=1993 & 
             df$file_end$year+1900  >= 2003)

files_to_load <- df$file_name[df_index]
```

Comment: I get an error, saying Error in year(df$file_start) : could not find function "year"

Comment: Darn, missed the lubridate library call. edited now. Thanks for the heads up.